# check if point lies on line segment

Tags: c, geometry, computational-geometry, postgis

I am confusing, I want check if a point lies on the a line segment.
I google it, but I receive basically two different answers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment

and

http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_C/Check_Point_Lies_line_Segment.html

What is the correct answer? i want this algorithm (in C language is better) for geometry applications, like the postgis.

Comment: Having two different answers to the same problem doesn't mean that one's wrong.

Comment: From what I see they use two different representations of a line segment. One time **begin** and **end** coordinates (C algorithm). And one time **begin** and **direction/length** vector (Wikipedia).

Comment: But what is the difference? when i use the wikipedia solution and another?

Comment: Same thing, but begin/end is probably easier to program than degree/length vectors. begin/vector will probably be at least 1 more step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic cannot store every number that you want it to. At some point, it has to approximate. Now, I'm guessing, the algorithm you got from Wikipedia is telling you:

```
y=mx+b
```

You know `m`, you know `b`, now plug in and make sure the equation holds true. Works great for mathematics. (The square root of 2 ) squared is equal to the square root of 4.

But now imagine you do that on a computer. The square root of 4 will come out exactly as 2, because computers are great at holding small integer numbers. However, your right hand side, the square root of 2, is going to be a bit off. You had to cut off some of the digits of it, so when you squared it, it might be 1.999998 or something like that. To accommodate for this, you need to check that `y is approx. mx+b`, so:

```
tolerance = .01
x,y
rhs = m*x + b //right hand side
dif = abs(rhs - y)
if dif < tolerance //the point is approximately on the segment
```

Then you'll have to check the bounding box for it (find max x,y, min x,y)

Of course, these methods aren't perfect (http://xkcd.com/217/) but for most practical applications, they will hold true enough. If you REALLY need exact numbers, I would suggest using Wolfram Alpha (I hear there's some API or something) or just writing your own exact number library.

Answer (score 2):

Before proceeding it would be helpful to know if you just have a graphical representation of the line somehow or if you actually have the formula that created the line. Since you said "line" and not "plane" I presume we are talking about a 2D line.

If you have the formula for the line then the answer is simple, substitute the points x,y value into the formula and if the formula is valid then the point is on the line.

For example, if the line was y = 2x + 1.5 and your point is (1,1)

1 = 1(1) + 1.5
1 = 3.5 is false, so the point doesn't lie on the line

The same works for any line formula in 2D or 3D regardless of the number of variables or the form of the line..

x + 2y = 0
1.5x + 12y - 4z = 84

Just pop in the point you are working with and if both sides of the equation are equal then the point is on the line (or plane).

If you are looking for a graphical solution, such as having a bitmap of a road map or something like that and wanting to know if the place where someone clicked is "on the line of the road" then that's a completely different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both are right.

Only keep in mind that Turbo C is terribly old and now outside the standard. void main() for example should not be used (it is int main() instead)

Also don't use comparisons (==) in floating point in C, because floating point is imprecise, this is why the Turbo C code has < 0.001 %% > 0.001 style.